# Wamp: Phpmyadmin shows blank page, localhost page is working

Tags: apache, phpmyadmin, wamp

I have installed Wamp on my computer (Win 8).

Since I had IIS installed also I changed the ports to 8080 instead in apache -> httpd.conf. Both on Listen and on ServerName. And I unchecked the IIS thing in Windows programs. (Sorry don't know what it's called my OS is in Swedish).

My hosts file only has: 127.0.0.1 localhost.

When I did that I got the localhost:8080 to work.

But when I try to access phpmyadmin it just shows a blank page. I have also tried opening Wamp as an administrator. And I have re-installed Wamp multiple times.

Now I need some help, feel like I am running out of options. I am a newbie so please don't make it complicated =) Thanks!

Comment: config.inc.php - one of the lines was missing a ";".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up with installing XAMPP and found out that it was a problem with port 443. Then I just opened XAMPP as administrator and it magically worked! =)

Comment: Worked with WAMP, seems like it needs admin rights.

Answer (score 8):

Try launching phpMyAdmin using

```
http://localhost:8080/phpmyadmin
```

If that works then its an IPV4/IPV6 confusion, Apache now listens to both ip address ranges by default and browsers tend to pick either IPV4 or IPV6 addresses for no apparent reasons. Add this line to your HOSTS file to associate localhost with the IPV6 loopback address

```
::1  localhost
```

Also check the phpMyAdmin config security, edit `?\wamp\alias\phpmyadmin.conf`

If you are using Apache 2.2.x, change the `Allow` it to look like this

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin3.5.1/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1 localhost ::1
</Directory>
```

If you are using Apache 2.4.x, change the whole `Directory` section to look like this

```
<Directory "d:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin4.0.4/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI
    AllowOverride all
    Require local
</Directory>
```

If you are using sqlbuddy or webgrind their config files also need changing in the same way in `?:\wamp\alias\...`

Answer (score 7):

For me it has some problems with sessions... so first, try to login with another browser like Firefox or something else and if it works in that browser you have to **clear your browser cache** ...
 
 
**simply use Ctrl+F5 for example 3 times** or clear all cookies from your browser settings...

Answer (score 4):

This happened to me and I fixed it by quitting Skype (I guess it was a port collision) and then stopping all services then turning them back on.

Comment: Dude, thank you! So random! This happened with me using UniServer Zero XII. I have used skype with it for awhile with no issues, but this seems to have resolved it. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I realize that this is an old question, but I came across a situation that wasn't covered by the above solutions, so I'll put it here for posterity:

If you're using phpMyAdmin < 4.2.12, make sure your browser is allowing JavaScript on localhost.

PhpMyAdmin is heavily dependent on JavaScript, and although there is a `<noscript>` tag in the DOM, some versions (like 4.1.2) have a CSS declaration that says:

```
html {
    display: none;
}
```

It then uses JavaScript to make it visible after the page loads, for cross-framing protection. As a result, the user can't see the `<noscript>` section telling them to turn on JavaScript, or the rest of the page for that matter.

This issue is fairly version-specific, as it seems to have been introduced in 4.x and fixed in 4.2.12 ([see related bug report](http://sourceforge.net/p/phpmyadmin/bugs/4574/)). So if you come across this issue, after you enable JavaScript, try upgrading to a newer version of phpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 0):

Personally my issue was with the `php.ini` file. After looking through the error log some of the values I put in were incorrect. By resetting them in the `php.ini` this allowed `phpmyadmin` to load properly.

Comment: This worked for me. i turn Off display_errors and display_startup_errors in php.ini and then service apache2 restart. now phpmyadmin loading without issue. Thank you @user4586611 i do not who given it negative feedback. but it really helped me.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this blank page problem is fairly easy. Simply modify this line in the PHPMyAdmin/config.inc.php

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host']          = 'localhost';
```

to this:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host']          = '127.0.0.1';
```

In the above code, you’re changing your name server to 127.0.0.1 in order to use TCP/IP connection. After this, you should be able to see your PhpMyAdmin page by opening in your browser the address http://127.0.0.1/PhpMyAdmin

For more solutions .. >

http://www.karinamyers.com/howto-fix-phpmyadmin-displays-blank-page-after-logging-inhowto-fix-phpmyadmin-muestra-pagina-en-blanco-despues-de-logeo/

Answer (score 0):

JUST change the port to 81, that worked for me . the was a conflict on port 80 with microsft.

Comment: Is "microsft" (*sic*) supposed to be a software? Please be more specific (and without typos).

Comment: @DelightedD0D Sure, I can guess that "microsft" (sic) probably means "IIS", but then why not use the correct word? This is not a chat room, this is supposed to be a reusable QA base. If Allen wants to get as much reputation as you have, he will have to learn how to express himself as precisely as you do.

Comment: @Aurélien ok, that's a fair point. Allen is actually referring to various Microsoft programs that use port 80 by default, the most common of which are Skype and IIS.Though to be fair, I was already aware of this issue so it seemed more obvious to me than it probably would to someone not familiar with it and clarification would have been better :)

Answer (score 0):

Its simple solution change memory_limit to -1, i.e memory_limit = -1 in php.ini file and restart the wamp.

This works

Answer (score 0):

Some may change the memory limit by reading what is written above it in the php.ini file.

; Maximum amount of memory a script may consume (128MB)
; http://php.net/memory-limit
memory_limit = 128M

They may change the 128M to 128MB if tinkering. It's best you enter the right credentials because the slightest mistake could have you scratching your head for hours. If you don't know.. don't change anything and seek help or best, if you don't know, you shouldn't be changing anything at all.

This has nothing to do with ports.. however, it has to do with the blank page under phpmyadmin log in and it may help someone that visits this thread.
Memory limit, post_max_size and upload_max_filesize are some of the most changed lines in an ini file and should really be separated out in a future host releases because as said above a slight change or an accidental removal of any text in there can bring your whole site crashing down.

Regarding Ports..I work with Wampserver and its a common problem that anti virus apps installed within Windows take up the same ports. Disabling these if not needed is and option but (**NOT recommended**). You can however change the ports that wampserver points to in your config.